# simpledateformat localizing wrong months name list

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I created Month-year picker.It was working fine but from couple of days it's creating problem. I was fetching months name list using **Simpledateformat localization.** But now it's repeating some months name. I don't know why?
please help me out of it.
**This is my code:**

```
private static String[] monthsList() {
    if (MONTHS_LIST == null) {
        int[] months = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
        String[] stringMonths = new String[months.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat(MONTH_FORMAT, Locale.US);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, months[i]);
            String monthName = monthDate.format(calendar.getTime());
            stringMonths[i] = capitalize(monthName);
        }
        MONTHS_LIST = stringMonths;
    }
    return MONTHS_LIST;
}
```

Output:

it's the screenshot of Month picker, in which it showing march in place of Feb

[image: it's the screenshot of Month picker, in which it showing march in place of Feb]

Comment: The years are also off... It's not clear how you're calling this method, but storing a static array variable is likely the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do little bit changes inside your code and now it is giving me the accurate name of months. I also put **Log.e** for check the name.

```
private static String[] monthsList() {
    if (MONTHS_LIST == null) {
        int[] months = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
        String[] stringMonths = new String[months.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, months[i]);
            String monthName = monthDate.format(calendar.getTime());
            stringMonths[i] = capitalize(monthName);

            Log.e("month name",monthName);
        }
        MONTHS_LIST = stringMonths;
    }
    return MONTHS_LIST;
}
```

> Below I put log screenshot for proof.
> [image]

Comment: So strange.... Same changes I made before, in my codes. That time it was not responding properly but now again it's working fine.... Thanks for help bud :)

Comment: If the answer is right then upvote and set as correct answer so it will helps others also.